# Search function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is my line of code to search the information from the database. I am trying to display the result obtained from the execution of this line. Should I just use a message box or use any object to display it? I do not want to use dataset.

```
 ACommanad.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students where StudentID =" & DeleteRecordTextBox.Text & ""
```

Comment: You should look into parameterized queries.

Comment: I am instructed to do it this way without using the parameter

Comment: This all depends on the requirements of your client and like Styxxy said, use parameterized queries.

Comment: No one would instruct you to do this without parameters, as it's a dangerous SQL injection risk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: I would say "it depends", how are you going to use it etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A message box is perfectly acceptable way to display something to the user.